# How can one get the running version of selenium, selenium server, or selenium webdriver programmatically?

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm running automated tests in several environments and need to know what is actually being used at run time.

I'm seeing different issues with identical Ruby scripts and would like to be able to capture as many environmental parameters as possible during the runs so they can be included in the run reports to help narrow down possible causes for the differences.

All environments are running Windows 7 64 SP1 and Ruby 2.0.0p451 (2014-02-24) [i386-mingw32].  Most serious issues are with IE (really??) and all environments are running the same IE version and build.

Any suggestions are most welcome.

pat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the version of a gem from the `source_location` of a method of one of its classes. For example:

```
Selenium::WebDriver.method(:for).source_location.first[/selenium-webdriver-\d+(?:\.\d+)*/]
=> "selenium-webdriver-2.53.0"
```

Comment: am clearly not putting it in the right place in this mess of code I've got:  getting uninitialized constant error for Selenium::Webdriver.   Will keep trying.

Comment: Aha!   Changed Webdriver to camel case: WebDriver and lo and behold!  it worked!

Answer (score 1):

A bit ugly but I finally got something that works for iedriverserver and chromedriver, the trick being to get the sysout and syserr as well as the pid so the process can be killed.

```
r, w = IO.pipe
pid1 = Process.spawn('iedriverserver', :out => w, :err => [:child, :out])
puts "#{__LINE__}: #{pid1}"
sleep(1)
k = Process.kill('KILL', pid1)
puts "#{__LINE__}: #{k}"
w.close
pid2, status = Process.wait2
puts "#{__LINE__}: #{pid2}, #{status}"
out = r.read
r.close
puts out
```

(Finally figured out the code markup... ;) )

Answer (score 0):

You could get the version of the driver by sending the `status` command to the driver:

```rb
require "selenium-webdriver"

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :ie
driver.navigate.to "http://stackoverflow.com/"

puts driver.send(:bridge).status
```

Comment: Here is what I get with the status command right after navigating to a url:

{"os"=>{"arch"=>"x86", "name"=>"WINNT", "version"=>"unknown"}, "build"=>{"revision"=>"unknown", "time"=>"unknown", "version"=>"unknown"}}

Comment: using firefox for above

Comment: For Chrome and Firefox, the version of the driver is available in `driver.capabilities`.

Comment: with FF I get this out of [browser].driver.capabilities:
`code`--- !ruby/object:Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities
capabilities:
  :browser_name: firefox
  :version: 38.8.0
  :platform: :windows
  :javascript_enabled: true
  :css_selectors_enabled: true
  :takes_screenshot: true
  :native_events: false
  :rotatable: false
  :firefox_profile: 
  :proxy: 
  handlesAlerts: true
  webStorageEnabled: true
  applicationCacheEnabled: true
  databaseEnabled: true
  locationContextEnabled: true
  acceptSslCerts: true
`code`
Nothing about the driver version

Comment: Am talking about ChromeDriver, IEDriverServer, etc.

Comment: My bad, the capabilities only gives the version of the driver for Chrome. Anyway, for Firefox, the version of the driver is the same as the version of the client or standalone server.

Comment: It seems that there no simple single way to get the version of each driver. You can also get some info from the remote server with this url: http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub/error